# Warning: Cannot reinitialise DataTable - How to add scroll options with a ready function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This throws an error. (Warning: Cannot reinitialise DataTable)  I looked at the different options but I think it has something to do with the ready function.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Database').DataTable({
      responsive: true        
    });
});
</script>
<script>
$('#Database').DataTable({
      scrollX: true        
    });
</script>
```

This does not thrown an error but does not work.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Database').DataTable({
      responsive: true, 
      scrollX: true
    });
});
</script>
```

I need my database to scroll horizontal with the ready function with issues.

PHP/MySQLi Code

```
<div class="panel-body">
                        <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="Database">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                    <th>Client's ID</th>
                                     <th>Client's Business Name</th>
                                     <th>Time</th>
                                    <th>Hours</th>
                                    <th>Pay</th>

                                 </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
<?PHP
$conn = mysqli_connect("","","","");

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "Select * from Database WHERE ID = '".$_SESSION['id']."'");

while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{

echo "<tr>
<td>".$result['Status']."</td>
<td>".$result['Client_ID']."</td>
<td>".$result['Client_Business_Name']."</td>
<td>".$result['Date']."</td>
<td>".$result['Time']."</td>
<td>".$result['Total_Hours']."</td>
   </tr>";

 }
 mysqli_close($conn);
 ?>


                            </tbody>
                        </table>

                        <div class="well">
                            <h4></h4>
                            <p>
                            </p>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
```

Comment: What version of datatables are you using?

Comment: JQuery 3.1.0  MYSQL 5.6 is the database.

Answer (score 0):

first block of code is normal to throw an error. You can not reinitialize datatable. Final.

Second block is OK. You just need scrollX: true, as a concept responsive is the opposite of X scrolling.

```
$('#Database').DataTable({
  scrollX: true
});
```

Comment: You just need scrollX: true, as a concept responsive is the opposite of X scrolling. - Not sure what you mean. I need the database to scroll horizontal but the second block does not work. Could you explain a little more detail.

Comment: Please provide a link so I can observe the behavior you are reporting. Check out this link http://jsfiddle.net/alpenzoo/x4fx0az9/ Comment scrollX and uncomment responsive, resize preview pane and tell me if that's what you need.